# How to notify the data is change from sqlite to recycler view?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have a application that contain `RecyclerView` and `FragmentDialog` , and I get data from user to `sqlite` and all is working ,
but the problem is when i add data to sql and display it in `RecyclerView` i have to restart the app to show the data , how can i notify that data is changed ???

This is my `DialogFragment`

```
public class addAction extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    EditText addTitle, addDesc;
    Button add, clear,close;
    private DatabaseHelpher db;
    String Title,Des;

    public addAction() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.addaction, container, false);
        addTitle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.todotitle);
        addDesc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tododescription);
        add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.addbutton);
        add.setOnClickListener(this);
        close = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Close);
        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        clear = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                addTitle.setText("");
                addDesc.setText("");
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getDialog().setTitle("Add Action");
        db = new DatabaseHelpher(getContext());
    }

    private void insert() {
        Title = addTitle.getText().toString();
        Des= addDesc.getText().toString();
        db.insertIntoDB(Title, Des);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (addTitle.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            addTitle.setError(" Title is required!");
        } else if (addDesc.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            addDesc.setError(" Postion is required!");
        }
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"your data is saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        insert();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    List<ToDoModule> dbList;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    DatabaseHelpher helpher;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        helpher = new DatabaseHelpher(this);
        dbList= new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
        dbList = helpher.getDataFromDB();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.AppRecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
        this.dbList =helpher.getDataFromDB();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_name);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                addAction add = new addAction();
                add.show(fm,"fragment_edit_name");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

`getdata()` method from `SQlHelper`

```
public List<ToDoModule> getDataFromDB(){
    List<ToDoModule> modelList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
    String query = "select * from "+ TODO_TABLE;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            ToDoModule model = new ToDoModule();
            model.setActionTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            model.setActionDesc(cursor.getString(2));
            modelList.add(model);
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return modelList;
}
```

**RecyclerViewAdapter**

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    static List<ToDoModule> dbList;
    static Context context;

    RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<ToDoModule> dbList ){
        this.dbList = new ArrayList<ToDoModule>();
        this.context = context;
        this.dbList = dbList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.actionitems, null);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.Title.setText(dbList.get(position).getActionTitle());
        holder.Desc.setText(dbList.get(position).getActionDesc());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbList.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
        public TextView Title,Desc;
        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            Title = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.todotitle);
            Desc = (TextView)itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.des);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a CursorLoader. with cursorreycleradapter https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b

Comment: thank you for your answer but can you apply this in my app , iam beginner in android !

Comment: No i won't. But you should probably trying doing something on your own first then if you end up in problems try posting relevant parts on stackverflow and i am sure someone will be around to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a function in MainActivity to update data of in recycler view. Then call that function from dialog fragment.
In MainActivity

```
public void updateData(){
       dbList =helpher.getDataFromDB();
       mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);
       mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

And in dialog fragment you can do same thing using interface or casting activity instance to MainActivity

```
((MainActivity) grtActivity()).updateData();
```

Or do it using an interface.

Comment: thank you for answer , but its not wokring , 

@nikka

Comment: Updated answer, also call update data function after adding data to database

Comment: Glad that U could help.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The problem is in these 2 lines.</strike>

mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this,dbList);

this.dbList =helpher.getDataFromDB();

First you set a reference of dbList to the adapter and then you change the refernece of the list to a list you create in getDataFromDB() and the list in the adapter stays the old one with no items.

in order to fix that change the second line of this code to 
this.dbList.addAll(helpder.getDataFromDB());

and than make sure you call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

EDIT: Nevermind it seems you call the db before that anyway.
Are you sure there are items in the db?

Comment: hmmm i think you dont understand me , yes sure the item in the db and when i restart the app , the item is display ,, i want display when click on add button ,, without restart the app ?